# Breath of the wild Fahrenheit/Celsius

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Breath of the wild, the game shows the temperature on the map screen in  Fahrenheit. I do not use Fahrenheit where I live. Is there any way to change that to Celsius?

If it helps, I am playing the Wii U version NTSC

Comment: What a surprise, clock/temperature types are determined by the region.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena I live in Canada, we use Celsius, and my Wii U is set to Canada

Comment: Hardcopy or Softcopy ?

Comment: I have the Hardcopy

Comment: take a look what version is that, usually it written in the box

Comment: I was under the impression that Nintendo of America and Nintendo of Canada sold separate copies of games. In addition to things being bilingual (English and French) I would imagine the temperature scale would be different as well.

Comment: I do know some french, so maybe I'l try that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no in game option to change it.

American version

- Temperature is Fahrenheit
- AM/PM Clock 12:00 - 11:59 am/pm

European version

- Temperature is Celsius
- 24 Hour Clock 0:00 to 23:59

some stupid workaround:

**Use an account tied to a different region, or change the consoles region.**

EDIT :

It seems you have a hardcopy version of the game which mean there is nothing you can do except buying **EU version** of the game.

Easier Way :

(°F - 32) x 5/9 = °C

Comment: I'l just have to start studying Fahrenheit. An option would be nice in an update though

Comment: @TheIdiotGamer. I wasn't even aware that the temperature had a unit. All I see is a little needle that moves towards different levels of hot or cold.

Comment: @Nolonar When you look at the slate map, it tells you the actual temperature in the bottom left corner.

Comment: Conversion isn't reallly required, to gauge, has a color range.  The displayed temperature isn't required to determine how cold it is

Answer (score 2):

Here are the following languages, for both the in-game text and the voices.

## In-Game Text (11 Languages)

- Deutsch
- English (Australia)
- English (United Kingdom)
- English (United States)
- Español (España)
- Español (Latinoamérica)
- Français (Canada)
- Français (France)
- Italiano
- Nederlands
- Русский
- 日本語

## Voices (9 Languages)

- Automatic (match system settings)
- Japanese
- English
- French (France)
- French (Canada)
- German
- Spanish (Spain)
- Spanish (Latin America)
- Italian
- Russian

Strangely, the game's language will be set to **English (United Kingdom)** if the system's language is set to **Português (Brasil)** or **Português (Portugal)**.

## Recap

### English (United States)

- Date & time format: 1/5/2017 12:34 AM (MM/DD/YYYY)★
- Temp. format: °F

### 日本語

- Date & time format: 2017/01/05 00:34 (YYYY/MM/DD)
- Temp. format: °C

### All Other Languages

- Date & time format: 05/01/2017 00:34 (DD/MM/YYYY)
- Temp. format: °C

★ Save points still use the 24-hour time format but use the same date format as the one on the system.

As for you, if you want to change to Celsius, you'll need to change your system language to **English (Australia)** or **English (United Kingdom)** by setting the region to **Australia/New Zealand** or **Europe**, respectively. You'll need to re-accept the EULA when you change regions.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted so much - maybe because it doesn't work on the Wii U hard copy? - but it works for the Switch hard copy, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Nintendo Switch hardcopy version of the game sold in Canada. In order to view the temperature in Celsius I had to change my system regions from `The Americas` to `Europe`.

I guess Nintendo doesn't consider Canada part of "The Americas"?

[image]